# How to create a fadeIn Chain Animation using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a side menu, when its opened it's children components needs to be fadeIn **respectively**
I have build simple animation with FadeIn but it effects all the child components at the same time.but i need them to be fadedin respectively. i.e lets say we have 5 child components, from top to bottom, they need to be faded in respectively.

Here you can look at what i am trying to do: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/TGXhaGc7D1W3bqHXS8

Here you can look at what i have accomplished so far: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/YR2YU7sNvvTpKp8I64

any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
For those who came here for answer:

In my situation, all i want is apply same animation for different components with a delay, so i created `Animated.MyComponent` and give it a delay prop, on my screen when i finished the first animation, i updated the delay prop with respect to the previous one's finished time.